# Trying to add css depending on browser width. Need Help (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, browser, resize

I'm trying to add a css file depending on the browser width and not sure how to go about it.

In this case, if the browser window is bigger than 1200 width it will add the css file. I know how to do this so it works with refresh but i want it so if the browser is being resized while active on the page the css file's will change.

Here's what I have at the moment, i'm probably going in the wrong direction im not too sure:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="smallS" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/default-960.css" /> 
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if (w > '1200') {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="largeS" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/default.css" />');
            }
            else {
                if($('#largeS').length > 0) {
                    $('#largeS').remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is what I had before, but its not what I'm looking to do:

```
if ((screen.width>=1024))
    {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/default.css" />');
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: window with is an integer and you are comparing it to a string `if (w > '1200')`, try taking out the single quotes of the `1200`

Comment: @amosrivera Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `document.write` only works when the document is being first parsed, not later.  You need to use DOM manipulation functions instead. Since you are using jQuery, this is greatly simplified:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        if (!$('#largeS').length) {
            $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="largeS" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/css/default.css" />');
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#largeS').remove();
    }
}).trigger('resize'); // invoke the handler immediately
```

Note that this uses `$('head').append()` and doesn't do an unnecessary check on the length of `$('#largeS')`.

Comment: @Daryl Could you give an example page, then, rather than having me shoot in the dark?

Comment: http://thefinishedbox.com/ - I have w3 Cache on atm, I can turn that off if you wish.

Comment: I see, well I moved it, if you look now it still loads small, but as soon as resize the window it switches to large css. Problem being is that even if you switch it with the browser being in a small minimized version it will still switch to big, also it doesn't remove it... what a nightmare lol.

Comment: jQuery was always loaded. Line 25 ( <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script> )

Comment: @Daryl Yes, but you're calling your code on line 14. You need to load jQuery before using it. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox. Have you uploaded your changed file?

Comment: @Daryl Have corrected my code -- I wrongly changed `$(window).width()`, which is the correct way to do what you want.

Comment: That works fantastic for the resize nice one, but the only problem is I need it to detect the window size on load aswell, not just on resize?

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thankyou so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

If using CSS3 is an option, mediaqueries will do this for you in a much nicer way.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

**Example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" href="/css/default.css" />
```

Comment: Media Queries are part of CSS2 spec http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries.html Which platforms are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Although you may not be able to code for CSS3 specifically, QuirksMode has an excellent article on using Javascript with media queries keeping standards in mind:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html

There is also a jQuery plugin that makes media queries available for all browsers: [project site](http://protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/) | [jquery site](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MediaQueries)